# How can I change value array into array

Tags: php

I have an array

```php
    <?

    $eventtest = Array
    (
        [ID] => 607375 
        [ATTENDEES_CODES] => Array
            (
                [0] => U62263
            )
    );

    ?>
```

How can I change `[0] => U62263` into [ATTENDEES_CODES] to `[0] => U62263 , [1] => U64024`?

Comment: Your array is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is adding an array element to a sub array.
You can do it like this:

```php
$eventtest[ATTENDEES_CODES][] = 'U64024';
```

This will add a new array value to ATTENDEES_CODES sub array.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't want to "change" the value per se, more like add another value to the `ATTENDREES_CODES` array which could be achieved through the following:

```php
$eventtest['ATTENDEES_CODES'][] = 'U64024';
```